# How to do this background transition in CSS

Tags: css, animation, linear-gradients

how can I animate a linear gradient use as background as it is in this video: https://vimeo.com/471351659 ? I tried the technique of one gradient, whith a big background size, where I animate the background-position property, but it hasn't been a success.
How can I set a good animation with the background-position property, to have a gradient for each of the image.

Comment: What you have tried? is a "simple" slideshow.

Comment: I've tried to create one giant gradiant, to use big background-size and then animate background-position but it doesn't really work

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely possible.

Personally, I'd take the approach of having two divs with `background: cover` and in an `window.setInterval()` callback, transitioning the `opacity` of the one in front (to be introduced) from zero to 1, then removing the one behind.